# Javascript - call a function multiple times but only have one effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I know I can easily work around this, but I'm looking for the best practice in this case.  This is a simplified version http://jsbin.com/isered/3/edit.  I'm trying create a function for reuse but I need it so that when the event is triggered (i.e. clicking on the anchor tag), it only appends the output area once, not for each time the function has been called.

**Jquery/Javascript**

```
$(function () {

   function foo () {
      $('a').on('click', function () {
      $('.asdf').append('poo');
    });
   }

   foo ();
   foo ();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href='#'>hello</a>
<a href='#'>world</a>

<p class='asdf'></p>
```

Comment: A working demo is great, but if the JSBin link rots, this question has no useful content. Could you provide the relevant code in the question as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/off/) the events before binding them:

```
function foo () {
  $('a').off('click').on('click', function () {
      $('.asdf').append('poo');       
  });
}
```

Though I don't understand why calling the function once and only once is not the best solution.

Comment: I'll give this a shot.  Again, this is a much simpler example than the one I have.

Comment: this is the shortest fix so I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a state variable, in this case a class:

```
$(function () {
  function foo() {
    $('a:not(.clicked)').on('click', function() {
      $(this).addClass('clicked');
      $('.asdf').append('poo');
    });
  }

  foo();
  foo();
});
```

Comment: I figured toggling a class/variable would be one way to solve it.  I awarded the other answer just b/c it was a little less code, but this would definitely be effective as well. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you did. Now I know how to do it without classes as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

I usually encounter this when I want to make a container only once but process the rest of the function on subsequent clicks as well.  In that case, I put a check for the container's existence as follows:

```
var foo = function(){
    $('a').on('click', function(ev){
       if (!$('.asdf .foo').length) {
           $('.asdf').append('<div class="foo">');
       }
       // do other click stuff here
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore.js already has this function.](http://underscorejs.org/#once)

So why re-invent the wheel.

> _.once(function)  Creates a version of the function that can only be called one time. Repeated calls to the modified function will have no
>   effect, returning the value from the original call. Useful for
>   initialization functions, instead of having to set a boolean flag and
>   then check it later.

[Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/j3eSa/2/)

```
$(function () {

  var foo = _.once(function() {
    $('a').on('click', function () {
      $('.asdf').append('poo');       
    });
  });

  foo ();
  foo ();
});
```

Comment: Could you make the font a tad larger?

Comment: Trying not to add another library if I can help it

Comment: @Blender - Unfortunately, that's as big as it gets. :)

Comment: Also, this code doesn't do what you think it does. Once you call `foo()`, the event will bind to the elements and clicking on them will result in the same behavior multiple times. It won't really solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @Blender - Not sure I follow. Though Matt's answer is certainly the way to go (no need to add a whole library for this), from what I can tell [his answer](http://jsfiddle.net/j3eSa/4/) and [my answer](http://jsfiddle.net/j3eSa/2/) are producing the same end result. Though I may certainly be missing something.

Comment: I misread the question, as the OP was binding events using a function (I'm not sure why) and he doesn't want to bind events twice to the same element. I was solving a different problem, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    function foo () {
        $('a').on('click', function () {
            var num = $('.asdf').text().length;
            if (num == 0) {
                $('.asdf').append('poopsicles');
            }
        });
    }

    foo();
    foo();
});
```

I guess this question has already been answered, but here ya go.

Comment: thanks Brandon, i was just reading how you have indent by four spaces for your code to show up properly.

Comment: Hey no problem! Here's a tip that'll help you out in the future. Instead of tediously adding the spaces, you can highlight your text and press the code formatting button in the top edit bar. It'll do the indenting for you and will certainly save you a bunch of time when trying to be the first one with an answer.

Comment: @BrandonBoone nice to know ... @ kenecaswell glad someone else picked up on the 'poo' reference ;)